# Modifying Creation Date from Filename for mp4 videos

Tags: date, video, metadata, avi, datecreated

I have a bunch of DV avi videos which I want to cut together. I managed to save the Creation Date out so the videos are named after their creation date. So after I cut them together, I still have the original date of the creation. But then I would like to put that date back to the metadata, which is modified after being cut together and converted from DV avi to mp4.

I am trying with exiftool, but I am a total noob and I cannot use it properly.
The final question is. Is there a possibility to batch change the "date created" metadata from the filenames?

the filename looks like this: YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS.mp4
I want to put it into the date created metatag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lots of searching, I finally found a solution!

http://www.advancedrenamer.com/user_guide/method_timestamp